Smarter way to overload methods?
I have a class called Block that has a Draw method. I want to make a function that draws a group of blocks all at once. Since some groups are Arrays and some are lists, I had to add an overload that basically does the same thing as the base function but just takes in a different type of parameter. Any ideas on how to improve this code?
public static void DrawAll(Block[] arr) {
    foreach(Block b in arr)
        b.Draw();
}

public static void DrawAll(List<Block> arr) {
    foreach(Block b in arr)
        b.Draw();
}

I tried looking into Generics but I can't iterate through T because the compiler doesn't know it's a collection of blocks.
// Doesn't work
public static void DrawAll<T>(T arr) {
    foreach(var b in arr)
        b.Draw();
}

Using the is keyword and casting also doesn't work because, from what I understand, you can't make two different casts in the same if statement. So I'll have to separate the casts and that just makes the code look even worse:
// Even dummer than just doing the overload
public static void DrawAll<T>(T arr) {
    if (arr is Block[] blocksA)
        foreach(Block b in blocksA)
            b.Draw();

    else if (arr is List<Block> blocksL) 
        foreach(Block b in blocksL)
            b.Draw();

    else throw new Exception("not a collection of blocks");
}


IEnumerable<Block>

What shingo is implying is that both an Array and a List are IEnumerable, and if you write a single implementation that takes an IEnumerable as a parameter, then you can pass either Block[] or List as an argument.

@Wyck, or the result of an unrealised LINQ query or anything else that implements that incredibly common interface.

What you need is a useful common base type of List<T> and T[] or an interface implemented by both of them.

If you don't need the index (e.g. because you are using foreach), then IEnumerable<Block> will work for all kinds of collections and also (unrealized) results of LINQ expressions, e.g.: blocks.Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith("A")).
public static void DrawAll(IEnumerable<Block> blocks) {
     foreach(Block b in blocks)
         b.Draw();
}


If you need the index (e.g. because you are using for), then IList<Block> will accept List<Block> as well as Block[].
// E.g. drawing blocks in reverse order
public static void DrawAll(IList<Block> blocks) {
     for (int i = blocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         blocks[i].Draw();
}



